# Consuming DLLs in VB.net - Multiple doubts

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, dll

I have been self reading dynamic libraries and I have huge mix inside my head.

1. The "imports" statement will tell the compiler what namespaces I want to use.
   Q1. ¿Do all DLL's have namespaces?.
   Q2. Is it related to the term "managed dll"? How?.
   Q3. ¿Could I still use contents in the DLL without using the "imports" and the correct namespace for the resource I want?.
2. When people talk about a .NET Wrapper for a DLL...
   Q1. ¿Does it mean I will be able to consume it from any of the 3 .NET languages without a problem and the compiler?.
   Q2. If Q1 is correct, who takes care of all the "casting" between C# datatypes and VB?.

Comment: `Imports` is not required in principle. It is only there to save typing. You can use anything without it. ".NET wrapper" is for unmanaged dlls which is a different subject. You can use any .NET dll in any .NET language without "casting".

Comment: Thanks for your help. So if the guy who wrapped the dll to make it usable on c#, the visual studio engine make it also usable for vb.net.